# Problem trying to copy portion of a string in C

Tags: c, string, parsing

I'm trying to copy from a string up to the first \n. I can't use strtok for this, as I need strtok for something else and it would overwrite it's state.

This is the string:

```
char fileCopy[] = "HELLO: LD X'0A\nJMP HELLO\n";
```

Here is the code I wrote, with debug prints:

```
char currLine [255] = {0};
int i = -1;
while (fileCopy[++i] != '\n')
{
    currLine[i] = fileCopy[i];
    printf("%i %c -> %c\n", i, fileCopy[i], currLine[i]);
}
currLine[i] = '\0';
i++;
printf("%s\n", currLine);
```

When I run it, it prints this for some reason:

```
0  -> 
1  ->
2  ->
3  ->
4 ♦ -> ♦
5  ->
6  -> 
7  ->
8 D -> D
9   ->
10 X -> X
11 ' -> '
12 0 -> 0
13 A -> A
```

Which is obviously not the right characters, and the last print statement hangs and never prints.
If I instead use this for the last print statement:

```
printf("%s\n", *currLine);
```

It prints "(null)".

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If i copy your code, compile it with gcc and run it the output looks correct. Where and how are you executing the binary? Probably some encoding issues there?

Comment: Please include a complete, compilable example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce those results with the code given. However, I would recommend checking for a null terminator in addition to the endline byte.

Comment: You have an embarrassingly large collection of standard alternatives: `strchr()`, `strcspn()`, `strpbrk()`, and even `strstr()` could all be used to find the newline — and none of them would interfere with a `strtok()` sequence.

Comment: It looks like some other part of your program is clobbering `fileCopy`.  Try to produce a self-contained example that exhibits the problem.  The posted code does not.

Comment: You can "restart" `strtok()` yourself by giving it the appropriate start address and pattern.

Comment: I realized the problem was something else, not having to do with this section of code. @JonathanLeffler I used this code to making a scrolling window on the string.